# I have two passports, one is where the visa stamp is and other has no visa stamp. What is the step to use it?

Tags: visas, passports, passport-stamps

What are the steps when I travel from U.A.E to Philippines with my Indian passport where my residence visa from U.A.E was stamp and I have Philippine passport with no visa stamp on it.

What are the documents I need to carry with me?  I don't want any hassles when I travel, so urgently need some advice.

Comment: thank you for your quick response.  I don't know which passport i have to present in U.A.E while checking in and which one to present in the U.A.E immigration. Which passport i have to present when i enter the Philippines?

Answer (score 7):

At check-in (and possibly the boarding gate) you'll need to present the Philippine passport to prove you'll be able to enter the country. At immigration exiting the U.A.E. (if there is) you'll need to show the Indian passport with the visa to prove you were staying legally -- they shouldn't care where you're going, just that you had a visa to be in the U.A.E. and haven't overstayed.

At Philippines immigration present the Philippine passport, similarly they don't care where you've been and just want to make sure you're allow to enter the Philippines.

On the return leg reverse it depending where you're going, show the passport that proves you can enter your destination at check-in, show the Philippine passport at Philippine exit clearance, etc.

Be ready, in case anyone asks, to show the other passport and explain what you've done. But in most cases each person that looks at your passport is trying to confirm a specific thing and you just need to show the passport that proves that.

Comment: Once an immigration office was so bedazzled with the situation like this on entry that he forgot to put the entry stamp into my passport. I was detained for several hours upon leaving the country, while they were sorting out what's happened.